# Lucee 5, Nginx, and Docker Compose not finding sample index.cfm file

Tags: nginx, docker, lucee

I have set up a fairly vanilla `Dockerfile` to start with, just to see if I can get the sample `index.cfm` to run:

```
FROM lucee/lucee-nginx:preview
```

And the related `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "80:80"
```

When I run this, I get an Nginx `403 Forbidden` error. If I change the `ports` setting to `80:8080`, I get a Tomcat `404 Not Found` error.

I'm lost as to how to get this working with Docker Compose. How can I debug this, or is there a different way that I can configure Docker Compose to get it running?

Comment: `FROM lucee/lucee-nginx:preview`

The `preview` release is a little bit unstable, so stack overflow probably isn't the best place for support.

`FROM lucee/lucee-nginx:latest`

Try the `latest` tag for the official 4.5 release instead.  And if you can't get that working we can troubleshoot your set up.

Comment: Feel free to raise Docker specific issues for Lucee builds here https://github.com/lucee/lucee-dockerfiles/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newer builds of Lucee 5 work (release candidates especially), so this problem has since "sorted itself out."

See the section of the lucee-dockerfiles project for [Lucee 5 on Tomcat-8-jre with Nginx](https://github.com/lucee/lucee-dockerfiles/tree/master/lucee-nginx/5.0).